# How to iterate backwards in a matrix from a specific point?

Tags: python, matrix

If I have a 3x5 matrix, and I want to iterate backwards from point (i,j) to the beginning of the matrix what would be the best way of doing that?
Example:

```
matrix = [[1,0,2,0,1],
          [0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0]]
```

Example: from (1,1) to (0,0) in the matrix we would print out: `0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1`

I tried the following code but this doesn't work as it ends up "slicing" the matrix.

```
    for row in reversed(range(i+1)):
        for col in reversed(range(j+1)):
```

Comment: What do you actually mean by "iterate backwards from point (i,j) to the beginning of the matrix"? The meaning might seem obvious to you, but there are multiple possible interpretations.

Comment: Can you provide the desired output in form iterating backward over the matrix [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]] starting from  i,j=3,1

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: You also have to define your problem clearly.  Again, see "how to ask ...".

Comment: "iterate backwards from point (i, j) to the beginning of matrix". Essentially interate from (i, j) to (0,0) in a sequential manner. I will explain further. Example: from (1,1) to (0,0) in the matrix we would print out: ```0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1```

Answer (score -1):

```
d = [[print(matrix[row-i-1][col-j-1])for j in range(col)]for i in range(row)]
```

Comment: I think this might be a good answer, but it would be more helpful if you explained it a bit.

Comment: matrix = [[1,0,2,0,1],
          [0,0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,1,0,0]]
row = 3
col = 5
for i in range(row):
    for j in range(col):
        print(row-i-1,col-j-1) # index_row ,index_col